# No prompt for setting a passphrase in GPG Keychain

Tags: email, encryption, gnupg, passphrase

I am trying to use GPG Keychain with Thunderbird (version 60.5.1) and Enigmail (version 2.0.9 / 20181209-1409).

In the process of generating a key for the email address after setting the password and selecting "Generate Key" there is no prompt to set a passphrase but the keys appear to be generated alright.

Unfortunately every time I try to sign/encrypt a message in Thunderbird I am asked for the passphrase associated with that eMail address, which, having never been prompted to set while generating the key, I don’t have which leaves me stuck.

Can you please advise? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You said *"after setting the password..."* so does that password work for the keys that were generated immediately afterwards?